# Xcode's "Incomplete implementation" warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Sometimes I forget to implement a method in one of my classes, and Xcode displays a "Incomplete implementation" warning.

Is there any way in Xcode to see **which** method implementation is missing?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

In your error view (command+4, by default, or the 4th tab in the left hand view) you can click the little arrow next to the warning, and it should tell you

> Method definition for 'blah' not found

Comment: Ahh I missed that tiny little arrow. Thanks!

Comment: bless you, my child, so obvious in retrospect! I've been doing "binary search" uncommenting of half my headers at a time trying to see when the warning disappears!

Comment: You... are my hero. I'd searched for this several times before and never gotten an answer. So simple...

Comment: Tip: If you click on that line `Method definition for 'blah' not found` with the grey-circled-bang, Xcode 4.6.3 takes you to the .h header file and selects the method in question. That's a convenience for you to copy-paste that method's stub into the .m implementation file as a headstart in your writing the source code to flesh out that method. Unlike most IDEs, Xcode apparently lacks the feature to do that method stub creation drudgery on our behalf.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that sometimes the Log Navigator is the only way to show the actual problem - in at least one case, the error view didn't help me. To see the Log Navigator, you can use View > Navigators > Show Log Navigator (or ⌘7 by default).